# How to interrupt recvfrom using ctrl+c since Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From what [PEP 475](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/) said, socket.recvfrom won't return when Ctrl+C is pressed after python 3.4.

Just wondering how to be able to handle Ctrl+C by my code again, which would be quite convenient when I'm building a new UDP server for testing.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5555))

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(2048)
    if not data:
        # expected to be here when Ctrl+C is pressed
        print("client has exited")
        break
    print("received:", data.decode(), "from", addr)

s.close()
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27177870/8353711)?

Comment: @shaikmoeed looks like it doesn't help, it only gets interrupted when it receives another message.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this handler closure might be close to what you're looking for:

```py
import os
import signal
import socket


def create_handler(obj):
    def _handler(signum, frame):
        print(' received kill signal')
        # example obj method
        obj.close()
        signal.signal(signum, signal.SIG_DFL)
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signum)  # Rethrow signal without catching it

    return _handler


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5555))

# Alternatively SIGTSTP for ctrl+z
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, create_handler(s))

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(2048)
    if not data:
        # expected to be here when Ctrl+C is pressed
        print("client has exited")
        break
    print("received:", data.decode(), "from", addr)

s.close()
```

Comment: thanks, but according to my test, looks like that it only exit when it receives another new message from client